# Join two collection in mongoose using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to join two collection in `MongoDB`. I have two collections 1. student 2. course.

**student collection:**

[image]

**course collection**

[image]

I tried some code but that is not working.

This is my code

**student.js**

```
router.get('/student/:id', function(req, res){

    Student.find({_id:req.params.id}, function(err, user){
        res.send(user);
    })
})
```

This is **Schema**:

**student.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let StudentSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
        name:{
            type: String
        },
        email:{
            type: String
        },
        phone:{
            type: String
        },
        password:{
            type: String
        },
        course :[{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Course'
        }]
    }, { collection: 'student' });


const Student = module.exports = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
```

**course.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let CourseSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    student_id:{
        type: String
    },
    course_name:{
        type: String
    },
    course_cost:{
        type: String
    }
    }, { collection: 'course' });


const Course = module.exports = mongoose.model('Course', CourseSchema);
```

**Result:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to query like this :

> **findOne** : to find single document (return object {} )
>
> **find** : to find multiple documents (return array [])

```
Student.findOne({_id:req.params.id}, function(err, student){
       if(!err && student){
           Courses.find({student_id:req.params.id},function(error,courses){
                if(!error && courses){
                    student.courses=courses;
                }else{
                    student.courses=[];
                }
                res.send(student);
           });
       }
});
```

currently you are getting  `course :[]` , because there is no field found in students collection , as you can see in photo-1

you need to set `course :["coures_id1","coures_id2"]` while inserting a document in student collection.

then you can use [mongoose populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to populate course into students

```
Student.findOne({_id:req.params.id}).populate('course').exec(function(err,student){
     res.send(student);
});
```

so after than no need to store , `student_id` field in courses collection , as you are getting from students collection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you mean i want to create course field in StudentSchema right ?

Comment: @Madhumitha , you have already addded course in student schema , but you havent set value for that , so thats why it is not in database

Comment: Yes i got the result

Comment: Actually i through `_id` is `primary key`, so if am store that `_id` to `course` colection means we can get records. I mean `student_id` is act as `foreign key`

Comment: as you are using mongodb as database ,  you can store ids of courses as array in students collection , in MYSQL you can do like this (primary , foreign), but in mongodb you can store any type complex document .

Comment: by this way your computation time is (query exacution time decrease) only 1 query , while collecting data from 2 collection may increase time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189796/discussion-between-madhumitha-and-saurabh-mistry).